# NotImplementedException when trying to use custom class for user setting

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to save a window's position as a user setting so I can restore it when my app starts up. I add a setting using the designer of this type:

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace MyApp.Framework
{
   [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
   public class SavedWindowSettings
   {
      public double Left { get; set; }
      public double Top { get; set; }

      public SavedWindowSettings()
      {
      }

      public SavedWindowSettings(double left, double top)
      {
         Left = left;
         Top = top;
      }
   }
}
```

It compiles, but when I run I get

```
System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'
```

but the last thing in the call stack is

```
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.BamlType bamlType, short typeId)
```

which doesn't help much. I think is has to do with App.config. If I change the type of the setting to string, my App.config has

```
     <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
     </sectionGroup>
```

and

```
     <userSettings>
       <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="MainWindowPlacement" serializeAs="String">
             <value />
          </setting>
       </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
     </userSettings>
```

sections. I tried adding them back in, changing `serializeAs` to `xml`, with the same exception. What am I missing?

Comment: `NotImplementedException` sure doesn't help much!

I've written up a guide on how to diagnose the underlying problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74460800/1688738.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After much screaming, I found that somehow, one of my libs didn't work correctly after I installed PrettyBin. No idea what, where or why, I like figuring out things for my self, but I was pretty much down to trying random things. Useless error message :)

Comment: Can you provide more details? What was the library? What is PrettyBin? What actually fixed your problem in the end?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that screams out is that you have no setter's defined for `Left` and `Top`.  Why don't you have:

```
public double Left { get; set; }
public double Top { get; set; }
```

The exception could be from the runtime reporting that there is no method for setting your props.

Comment: there must be another source code file we are not seeing then.  You sure your XAML is valid?