# NotImplementedException when loading xaml via System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml file containing a `ResourceDictionary` which I load during startup of my WPF GUI. This xaml file resides in the same assembly. Here's a minimal version of the code which triggers the issue:

```
var uri = new Uri("/MyAssemblyName;component/MyNamespace/ResDict.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(uri);
```

Here's the exception message:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception. Line number '197' and line position '11'.

InnerException
NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

And here is the full stacktrace:

```
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.BamlType bamlType, short typeId) Line 582
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(short typeId) Line 187
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_ConstructorParameterType() Line 1111
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord() Line 547
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.ReadKeys() Line 296
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetDeferrableContent(System.Windows.DeferrableContent deferrableContent) Line 1113
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.Create_BamlProperty_ResourceDictionary_DeferrableContent.AnonymousMethod__297_0(object target, object value) Line 6707
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(object instance, object value) Line 46
System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(System.Xaml.XamlMember member, object obj, object value) Line 294
System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(object inst, System.Xaml.XamlMember property, object value) Line 279
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.SetValue(object inst, System.Xaml.XamlMember property, object value) Line 2205
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ApplyPropertyValue(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx, System.Xaml.XamlMember prop, object value, bool onParent) Line 1619
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx) Line 2053
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember() Line 813
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(System.Xaml.XamlReader reader) Line 50
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, bool onlyLoadOneNode, bool skipJournaledProperties, bool shouldPassLineNumberInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack<System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlFrame> stack, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector) Line 267
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri) Line 148
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, System.Uri baseUri) Line 43
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext, object parent, bool closeStream) Line 1115
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext pc) Line 575
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri resourceLocator, bool bSkipJournaledProperties) Line 531
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri resourceLocator) Line 487
[... my code]
```

This has worked in the past, but stopped working recently when I upgraded the project files from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to target .NET 6.

There is no mention of a possible `NotImplementedException` in [the documentation for Application.LoadComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.loadcomponent?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

I have reduced my ResDict.xaml down to the minimal content which triggers the problem. And it looks like this:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyDataModel}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

It contains a single empty `DataTemplate` for a type in the same assembly. I can't see anything very special about that type, it's a pretty normal datamodel. I have tens of similar classes and corresponding `DataTemplates`, and I only see the crash for this particular one, no matter the content of the `DataTemplate` including when it's empty.

Any ideas how to debug?

The outer exception about 'Set property DeferrableContent' occurs in dozens of StackOverflow questions in all kinds of circumstances, so I have a hunch the inner exception is more relevant.

I can see other questions which mention the Baml2006 `NotImplementedException`, but they don't exactly apply to my case:

1. [WPF 4.0 Application load error in some environments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3850185/1688738)
2. [The method or operation is not implemented exception when trying to use custom class for user setting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50915449/1688738)
3. [Method or operation not implemented error on Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13007129/1688738)

Comment: Probable sufferers of the same unhelpfully buried exception:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/50915449/1688738 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13007129/1688738.

Answer (score 4):

Loading the xaml failed because the runtime could not locate an assembly referenced by the `DataTemplate`'s target type. The .NET code has (in my opinion) horrendous behaviour where it doesn't report the true problem -- the `NotImplementedException` appears to be a placeholder for some important code that they just never wrote!

Since this exception hides any number of actual underlying exceptions, here is how I diagnosed the problem.

First I [switched on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2022) step-through of .NET source code in the debugger. Then I could see the source line in Baml2006SchemaContext.cs that was throwing the exception. You can see the source [here](https://source.dot.net/#PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Markup/Baml2006/Baml2006SchemaContext.cs,565). I assume I cannot copy it into my answer for copyright reasons, so here is pseudocode:

```
private XamlType ResolveBamlType(string assemblyName)
{
    // Can't step into below voodoo method for which source is unavailable
    System.Reflection.Assembly ass = MS.Internal.GetLoadedAssembly(assemblyName);
    if (ass != null)
    {
        return new XamlType(ass);
    }

    // Here in the source appears an extended comment about how they should finish implementing the method
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

What it *should* do in my opinion is return some information about why it couldn't resolve the assembly. But it gave me a clue. I added a couple of lines to my code before loading the xaml file:

```
var ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("MyAssemblyName");
var _ = ass.DefinedTypes; // Access property and discard value
var uri = new Uri("/MyAssemblyName;component/MyNamespace/ResDict.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(uri);
```

The second line above throws a meaningful exception:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

OK, that's a real error I can now investigate! This is the exception I should have got instead of the `NotImplementedException`.

An assembly could fail to load properly for a variety of reasons so if you have this problem, try adding the above lines to see the real error.

*Weird side note 1: in my modified code above, my call to Assembly.Load is loading the very same assembly which contains the currently-executing lines of code... how can it fail if it's already running?*

*Weird side note 2: `Assembly.Load` succeeds without throwing an exception. It's only when I access certain properties on the returned object that an exception is thrown.*